# How to full vectorize this?

Tags: matlab, merge, time-series, vectorization

I write this little piece of code to syncronize two financial time series. I download some forex data and there are some missing trades. The ideia here is to get the biggest set and syncronize the others with this one.

For example i have a set with like this

```
    a= [20010110 2310 10;
       20010110 2311 20;
       20010110 2313 30]
    b= [20010110 2309 50;
    20010110 2312 52]
```

and i want then i get this

```
    c =[20010110 2310 50;;
       20010110 2311 50
       20010110 2313 52]
```

c is pretty much the same thing as a, but this is only a index.

so i write this

```
    function [setAjustado] =  ajustar(SetCorreto,SetParaAjustar)

    dataCorreto = SetCorreto(:,1); % get the date from the correct set
    dataAjustar = SetParaAjustar(:,1); % get the date from the set to be corrected 
    minCorreto = SetCorreto(:,2); % get the timeframe from the correct set
    minAjustar = SetParaAjustar(:,2);get the timeframe from the set to be corrected 
    setAjustado = zeros(size(SetCorreto)); %corrected set
    idxI = dataAjustar == dataCorreto(1); %generating the first range to search

     for i=2:size(SetCorreto,1)
     try

       if (i >1 && dataCorreto(i) ~= dataCorreto(i-1)) % if the dates are the same, i dont need to look for the range again
         idxI = dataAjustar == dataCorreto(i); % generate the range to search
         idxIa = find(idxI==1,1); % find the first index
       end

       idx =  find(minAjustar(idxI)>=minCorreto(i),1) +idxIa; % find the nearest occurency in the set to be corrected to match the correct set
       setAjustado(i,:) = SetParaAjustar(idx,:); %replace all the line. This line have prices close, max, low and open. 
       setAjustado(i,2) = minCorreto(i); %adjust the timeframe to match the correct set
     catch
        if i==1 % in case of i to be greater then the size of set to be corrected
          a=i;
        else
          a= i-1;
      end
     setAjustado(i,:) = setAjustado(a,:); % will copy the last line created in corrected set

      end
     end
```

But im thinking this thing is pretty slow... Can someone help me to speed this thing?

Tks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "syncrhonise".  What exactly is the computation you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data you posted and your comments, here is something I tried:

```
% first two columns are considered "keys", last one contains the values
a = [20010110 2310 10;
     20010110 2311 20;
     20010110 2313 30];
b = [20010110 2309 50;
     20010110 2312 52];

% get a row identifier for each instance
[~,~,ind] = unique([a(:,1:2);b(:,1:2)], 'rows');
ind_a = ind(1:size(a,1));
ind_b = ind(size(a,1)+1:end);

% merge the data
c = nan(max(ind),size(a,2));
c(ind_a,1:end-1) = a(:,1:end-1);
c(ind_b,:) = b;

% fill-in missing values from last know values
for i=2:size(c,1)
    if isnan(c(i,end))
        c(i,end) = c(i-1,end);
    end
end

% only keep instances matching A's rows
c = c(ind_a,:);
```

The result:

```
>> c
c =
    20010110        2310          50
    20010110        2311          50
    20010110        2313          52
```

If you actual data contains more columns, you'll need to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Amro, i made a little modification, and everything is working like charm

Thank you very much!

        % merge the data
        c = nan(max(ind),size(a,2));
        c(ind_a,1:2) = a(:,1:2);
        c(ind_b,:) = b;
       % fill-in missing values from last know values
        for i=2:size(c,1)
            if isnan(c(i,end))
                c(i,3:end) = c(i-1,3:end);
            end
        end